# Youtube API 3 play playlist songs in Background (inactive tab) in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

I have been working on a personal project of mine trying to learn Javascript. 
So far it is going good.

I am collecting youtube links from some external webpage and making a playlist from them and playing them one after another when first one finishes.

The system works as expected if I have the tab active but when I am doing something else in another tab but keep on listening to the song, it does not load automatically. 
The same case works both on Firefox and Safari.

I have researched without success before asking for help and know this was a "feature" from google Chrome team but I have seen another site tackle this problem even in inactive tab.

Since I am novice in this area, I am asking for help from StackOverflow community.

**On Chrome**
http://roll.io/#wi4umt!0   ---- This does not work in inactive tab 
http://8tracks.com/weedies/hip-hop-suite-vol-1#  ---- This works in inactive tab

If you find anything that can be of help, I would be very grateful.

Here is my Code that I have for youtube.

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(youtubeID, i) {
var rand = getRandomArbitrary();
var e = document.getElementById(youtubeID), t = document.createElement("img")
t.setAttribute("id", "youtube-icon"), t.style.cssText = "cursor:pointer;cursor:hand", e.appendChild(t);
var a = document.createElement("div");
a.setAttribute("id", "youtube-player"+i+rand), e.appendChild(a);
var o = function (e) {
    var a = e ? "pause.svg" : "play-button.svg";
    t.setAttribute("src", "/img/" + a)
};
e.onclick = function () {
    player.getPlayerState() === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING || player.getPlayerState() === YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING ? (player.pauseVideo(), o(!1)) : (player.playVideo(), o(!0))
};
var player = new YT.Player("youtube-player"+i+rand, {
    height: "0",
    width: "0",
    videoId: e.dataset.video,

    playerVars: {autoplay: e.dataset.autoplay, loop: e.dataset.loop},
    events: {
        onReady: function (e) {
            player.setPlaybackQuality("small"), o(player.getPlayerState() !== YT.PlayerState.CUED)
            player.unMute();
        }, onStateChange: function (e) {
            e.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED && o(!1)
        }
    }
})

return player;
}
```

Thank you :)